# How can I multiply an image against the alpha of another image in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, image, graphics

Having loaded two different images I want to do the following operation and obtain image3.

```
image1.red * image2.alpha = image3.red
image1.green * image2.alpha = image3.green
image1.blue * image2.alpha = image3.blue
```

I wrote the code in the link below for Android and was basically looking for the same functionality in Objective-C/Cocoa. 

http://www.ruibm.com/?p=184

Thanks,
Rui

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the above code relates to creating a rounded rectangle...unless the rounded rectangle is one either image1 or image2.  If it is, then you have to clamp the results to a max and/or a min.

Comment: The bitmap with the rounded rectangle in the code sample would be equivalent to image2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a rounded rectangle path and clip your image with it.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHBCGB

Comment: The point about the sample code isn't the rounded rectangle, it's the fact that I apply image2's (which happens to be a bitmap with a rounded rectangle) alpha to image1 colours and get a nice anti-aliased bitmap with rounded corners. I need to generalize this because image2 isn't easy to draw via code.

Comment: Try actually clicking the link and reading the documentation before you dismiss it. See all those pretty anti-aliased masks they show you how to use? Neat, huh?

Comment: Chill out dude! I did click the link and wanted to change my vote but stackoverflow wouldn't allow me anymore.